# ways to buy the six marbles

Tags: combinatorics

A boy wishes to buy exactly six marbles. There are four different colours of marbles available. In how many ways can he buy six marbles? hint:arrange 111 000000

Comment: **iur** different colors?

Comment: this is 'four'.

Comment: The hint means how many ways can you arrange six marbles and three dividers.

Comment: HINT: The question will most likely be closed due to the fact that it looks like a copy-paste from your homework assignment, and since you are not showing any effort attempting to solve it on your own. Hence, there is very little motivation for anyone here to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

It comes to solving on how many ways $6$ can be written as a sum of $4$ nonnegative integers.

Apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$
$n=4$ and $k=6$

So
$$\binom{4+6-1}{6}=\binom{9}{6}=84$$

Comment: the answer is 84.

Comment: The formula used in this answer is incorrect.  Also, you should explain where the formula comes from.

Comment: There are 4 different types of marbles I would like to chose 6 of them. This is a combination with repetition.